# Apply SVD Linear Regression in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, svd

I'm trying apply SVD Linear Regression in a points cloud. My representation of points set is a matrix with two colums, where first column is 'x' and second is 'y'. So, I get this plot:

[image: myplot]

How I can apply SVD linear regression to my point set with a function?
I've tried with this:

```
Regress_Lin<-function(data,label){
  #Calculating pseudomatrix of data    
  data<-cbind(data,rep(1,nrow(data)))
  data.svd <- svd(data)
  ds <- diag(1/data.svd$d)
  u <- data.svd$u
  v <- data.svd$v
  us <- as.matrix(u)
  vs <- as.matrix(v)
  #Calculating abline coefficients y=mx+b
  weights<-(vs%*%solve(ds)%*%t(u))%*%label
  m <- -(weights[1,1]/weights[2,1])
  b <- -(weights[3,1]/weights[2,1])
  c(m,b)
}
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any reason that `lm` won't work for you?

Comment: The point is that `lm` fits linear regressions. It uses the QR decomposition, not the SVD, but that shouldn't matter to the end result.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I need learn to use SVD and pseudoinverses to get my `abline` coefficients. The command `lm` works, but I don't know how it works. So, I know how to get pseudoinverse of my independent variable, but I don't know how to use it to get my coefficients.

Comment: It appears that you are expecting a tutorial on a particular matrix method. If this were my homework problem and I didn't have the linear algebra skills to do it and couldn't find worked examples in my textbook, I would be searching for code in the archives of SO and rhelp and doing google or rseek.org searching. (You are asked in the SO-help pages to demonstrate what sorts of efforts you have made.)

Comment: As a side note, you can perform principal component regression using the `pcr` function from the `pls` package (available on CRAN). I'm not sure if SVD is used under the hood, but in practice it should get you the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need SVD to compute the inverse of  [image: inverse of X] and then you get the Weights for Linear Regression as follows:

[image: Weights]  (This is the pseudoinverse of X)

So given that you have your `data` with the format `(x0, x1, x2)`, first:

Get [image: inverse of X] with SVD:

```
x <- t(data) %*% data
duv <- svd(x)
```

Once you have the singular value decomposition, x^-1 is computed as [image: inverse]

```
x.inv <- duv$v %*% diag(1 / duv$d) %*% t(duv$u)
```

Now, compute the pseudoinverse of X as [image: pseudoinverse]

```
x.pseudo.inv <- x.inv %*% t(data)
```

And now you can get the Weights doing [image: w]

```
w <- x.pseudo.inv %*% labels
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

If your problem is (actually) getting the regression line plotted, this works fine with `lm()`:

```
# simulate some data:
x = (1:100) + runif(100)*20; x = (1:100) + runif(100)*20
plot(x,y)
abline(lm(y~x))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know that `lm()` works, but I need to know how SVD works. I've tried to get the svd values of a matrix with `svd()` function, this returns three matrixes: `U`,`V` and `D`. It's supossed that `M=U%*%D%*%t(V)` but this matrix multiplication doesn't work. Why? I don't know...